# Embedded Instagram post with description: Same heights?

Tags: css, instagram, instagram-api

I have a page where I embed a few Instagram posts. All posts are embedded via the function if you see a picture and click on the right bottom corner on "Embed this".

I changed the width to 350px.

I searched for `responsive instagram embed` and found something for single post embeds.

Can someone check this fiddle and explain me what's wrong? :(

Thank you in Advance!

https://jsfiddle.net/ouqg0wj7/

**Code:**

```css
.row .col-sm-4 iframe {
  max-width: 350px;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"><blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-version="6" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:350px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:8px;"> <div style=" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50.0% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;"> <div style=" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAAGFBMVEUiIiI9PT0eHh4gIB4hIBkcHBwcHBwcHBydr+JQAAAACHRSTlMABA4YHyQsM5jtaMwAAADfSURBVDjL7ZVBEgMhCAQBAf//42xcNbpAqakcM0ftUmFAAIBE81IqBJdS3lS6zs3bIpB9WED3YYXFPmHRfT8sgyrCP1x8uEUxLMzNWElFOYCV6mHWWwMzdPEKHlhLw7NWJqkHc4uIZphavDzA2JPzUDsBZziNae2S6owH8xPmX8G7zzgKEOPUoYHvGz1TBCxMkd3kwNVbU0gKHkx+iZILf77IofhrY1nYFnB/lQPb79drWOyJVa/DAvg9B/rLB4cC+Nqgdz/TvBbBnr6GBReqn/nRmDgaQEej7WhonozjF+Y2I/fZou/qAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;"></div></div> <p style=" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/_h7TJTEIfv/" style=" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;" target="_blank">S M I L E  #bemarvelous #marvelousproducts #marvelousbeauty #beauty #style #hair #product #men #women #lovely #hairdresser #hairdesign #allblack #stylist #instyle #vogue #paris #moscow #milan #london #newyork #lissabon #berlin #stuttgart #germany #italy #russia #portugal #picoftheday #picture</a></p> <p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">Ein von @melo_modica gepostetes Foto am <time style=" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;" datetime="2015-12-20T22:17:57+00:00">20. Dez 2015 um 14:17 Uhr</time></p></div></blockquote></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-version="6" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:350px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:8px;"> <div style=" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50.0% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;"> <div style=" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAAGFBMVEUiIiI9PT0eHh4gIB4hIBkcHBwcHBwcHBydr+JQAAAACHRSTlMABA4YHyQsM5jtaMwAAADfSURBVDjL7ZVBEgMhCAQBAf//42xcNbpAqakcM0ftUmFAAIBE81IqBJdS3lS6zs3bIpB9WED3YYXFPmHRfT8sgyrCP1x8uEUxLMzNWElFOYCV6mHWWwMzdPEKHlhLw7NWJqkHc4uIZphavDzA2JPzUDsBZziNae2S6owH8xPmX8G7zzgKEOPUoYHvGz1TBCxMkd3kwNVbU0gKHkx+iZILf77IofhrY1nYFnB/lQPb79drWOyJVa/DAvg9B/rLB4cC+Nqgdz/TvBbBnr6GBReqn/nRmDgaQEej7WhonozjF+Y2I/fZou/qAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;"></div></div> <p style=" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/_WgapQQeNY/" style=" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;" target="_blank">My sweet brother @andreeeiiiii #mybrother #blogger #bloggers #blogging #howilovehim #whatuseeiswhatuget #larissssssssssssa #bemarvelous #beyourself #staystrong #dowhatsbestforyou</a></p> <p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">Ein von Lrissa (@larissssssssssssa) gepostetes Foto am <time style=" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;" datetime="2015-12-16T11:51:24+00:00">16. Dez 2015 um 3:51 Uhr</time></p></div></blockquote></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-version="6" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:350px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:8px;"> <div style=" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:62.5% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;"> <div style=" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAAGFBMVEUiIiI9PT0eHh4gIB4hIBkcHBwcHBwcHBydr+JQAAAACHRSTlMABA4YHyQsM5jtaMwAAADfSURBVDjL7ZVBEgMhCAQBAf//42xcNbpAqakcM0ftUmFAAIBE81IqBJdS3lS6zs3bIpB9WED3YYXFPmHRfT8sgyrCP1x8uEUxLMzNWElFOYCV6mHWWwMzdPEKHlhLw7NWJqkHc4uIZphavDzA2JPzUDsBZziNae2S6owH8xPmX8G7zzgKEOPUoYHvGz1TBCxMkd3kwNVbU0gKHkx+iZILf77IofhrY1nYFnB/lQPb79drWOyJVa/DAvg9B/rLB4cC+Nqgdz/TvBbBnr6GBReqn/nRmDgaQEej7WhonozjF+Y2I/fZou/qAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;"></div></div> <p style=" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/-y0E9vr9-E/" style=" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;" target="_blank">MARVELOUS ❤️#marvelous #bemarvelous #hair #salon #salondeluxe #haircolor #hairstyle #hairstylist #follow4follow #follower #follow #followme #instagood #instalike #likes #lfl#look #happy #beautiful #girl#emelüstün #me#selfie #keratin #volume #shine #glanz #love</a></p> <p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">Ein von Emel Üstün (@emelim82) gepostetes Foto am <time style=" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;" datetime="2015-12-02T15:10:33+00:00">2. Dez 2015 um 7:10 Uhr</time></p></div></blockquote></div>
</div>

<script async defer src="//platform.instagram.com/de_DE/embeds.js"></script>
```

**The final question:**
How I get this result?
[image: Expected result]
From current code?
[image: Current code result]

Comment: Whats the question? And post your code here too

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: I added the missing details. Thank's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can’t. It’s possible to make the Instagram iframes the same height (using `display: table-cell;` or JS) but it won’t look exactly like you want.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ouqg0wj7/3/

You would need access to the Instagram embed CSS to fix it.

Perhaps you could use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [CSS columns](https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/) instead?

Comment: Hmm thank you very much for your answer. Tomorrow I try this Masonry thing, but I hope there is another solution which is better :)
http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/06/how-to-create-masonry-based-instagram.html

Comment: No prob, good luck. (would you mind up-voting my answer if it was helpful? thanks!)

Comment: Or is there another solution for embed instagram posts? My thought is a php proxy for the iframe to add the custom css code :) But don't know if it's allowed and how to change... I think its the JavaScript which I must change then, too. Don't know if Instagram like that :D

Comment: Well, you won’t be able to do anything to the iframe’s content since it lives on an external server. You may be able to use Instagram’s API to create your own custom embeds, but that would be complicated and may violate their terms of service. I think Masonry is the simplest solution here :)